Run server env validation on `next build`
This is my src/config/server/ts
'use server';

import zod from 'zod';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('env should not be imported on the frontend!');
}

const schema = zod.object({
  API_KEY: zod.string({
    message: "API_KEY must be a string"
  }).min(1, "API_KEY must be at least 1 character long"),
});

export const env = schema.parse(process.env);


This is being used in src/utils/api.ts
'use server';

import { env } from '@config/server/env';

const api = new API({
  key: env.API_KEY,
});

export default api;


But since these are being used in src/api/, the validations are not being executed on next build command.
Where as I have a similar env file for client side as well, it is being triggered, because it is being used to compile the build.
How can I validate server env while next build?

Since schema.parse() throws an error if the schema fails, why not run the file src/config/server/env.ts file right before building?
Something like:
ts-node src/config/server/env.ts


ts-node allows you to run a TypeScript file without having to transpile it beforehand. You would have to install this with npm install --save-dev ts-node.

You could define a script in your package.json that handles this and then builds your project.
{
  "scripts": {
    "checks:env": "ts-node src/config/server/env.ts",
    "next:build": "next build",
    "build": "npm run checks:env && npm run next:build"
  }
}

And run this with:
npm run build

